# recover the currently loaded scripts in bash

Tags: macos, bash, .bash-profile

I just typed rm ~/.profile instead of `vim ~/.profile`. I have several terminal windows open still. Can I recover this easily, based on what was run when a different terminal started?

Comment: Restore a backup of ~/.profile.

Answer (score -1):

```
printenv
```

Will allow you to print out all current environmental variables in each terminal window

and

```
alias
```

Will allow you to print out all current aliases in each terminal window

Comment: This is pretty cryptic.  Can you expand your answer to explain what this does and how to implement it to solve the question?  Thanks.  [From review queue](http://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/502365)

Comment: just updated it

Comment: Might want to add `set` (all by itself), which does a lot of that and more.